# How do I find a copy of SQL Server 2000 so I can try to export the database I created to a current of SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server

I created a database in SQL Server 2000. I no longer have SQL Server 2000 but I need to use the database. I have it has a database and I also have it as a `.MDF` file where I can just attach it.

Each time I try to attach it or restore the `.bak` file, it I get this message:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore of database 'CSIAPP' failed.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.0194. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 14.00.1000. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: "version 14.00.1000" is SQL Server 2016 - which is **no longer** compatible with SQL Server 2000 files. If you want to salvage your `.mdf` or `.bak` file, you need to **first** install SQL Server 2008/2008 R2, then restore/attach your SQL Server 2000 file there, upgrade the internal database version (compatibility level), back it up again, and **then** you can restore it to SQL Server 2016. That's the price you pay when you're waiting to upgrade for so long ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch your Management studio with the latest service pack. Use Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 4
**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290211/how-to-obtain-the-latest-sql-server-2000-service-pack**